# Cannot consume interface or client of WCF Service - Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've had some trouble with my WCF service in the way that since I republished the service to azure, updated the service reference in Visual Studio, and all of a sudden in the code I cannot access the interface, client or methods of the service.

I can see the interface, client and methods when adding the service reference if I explore the service once it has been discovered in the window, however all of the items it discovers are not accessible/don't exist in the codebehind

If I reference a different service that runs similarly through WCF it works fine.

We have a WPF Client that can access the service as expected, but as soon as we consume it in Xamarin.iOS we cannot access the client which adds to the confusion..

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your WCF service only use the silverlight subset of WCF? And when you added the web reference did you use the SLsvcUtil.exe instead of SvcUtil.exe? See this Xamarin guide for more info: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ especially this section on creating the service reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/#Creating_a_Xamarin.Android_Application

Comment: @jgoldberger answer for the fix posted below, very interesting issue. Frustrating, but interesting.

Answer (score 0):

We found that this was because we were exposing a FaultContract with an exception that wasn't a custom one made by us when declaring one of our methods

Not quite sure why xamarin couldn't handle that but WPF could, however.

Comment: Thanks for posting the fix. Feel free to file a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com.